# Using text-icu library in Haskell on Mac OS

Tags: haskell, cabal, icu

I am trying to use the text-icu library as a dependency in a cabal package on Mac OS. I have icu installed but when I try to build my package cabal gives me this error:

- Missing C libraries: icui18n, icudata, icuuc

I'm am unsure what debugging steps to use.

Comment: Try to add library location to `extra-lib-dirs` and `extra-include-dirs` in the cabal configuration file.

Answer (score 26):

You can use either MacPorts or Homebrew to install the icu package, and have cabal refer to the custom header and library path:

## MacPorts

```
sudo port install icu
cabal install text-icu --extra-include-dirs=/opt/local/include --extra-lib-dirs=/opt/local/lib
```

## Homebrew

```
brew install icu4c
cabal install text-icu --extra-lib-dirs=/usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib --extra-include-dirs=/usr/local/opt/icu4c/include
```

Comment: Or you can use `brew install icu4c`. Then, installing the cabal package with `cabal install text-icu --extra-lib-dirs=/usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib --extra-include-dirs=/usr/local/opt/icu4c/include`

Comment: @danza - I did just that.

Comment: Note that it works exactly the same with Stack, just replace `cabal` with `stack`. For instance, if you installed the library with Homebrew, use `stack install text-icu --extra-lib-dirs=/usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib --extra-include-dirs=/usr/local/opt/icu4c/include`